# Structure of a Node.js Application

Tags: html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

My name is Alex.
Sorry for my rather bad Englisch because i come from Germany.
I just started programming with Node.js.
Previously i made some small static HTML and CSS websites.
I have some beginner questions (which might be dump).
I think these questions are very general for now and have therefore not included any code examples.

So far I have written a static HTML website which I host locally on my computer using Node.js and Express.

My Questions are:

1. Which actions within a web application should take place on the client side and which on the server side. For example, I have several buttons on the start page. With the help of which predefined users can log in. When clicking on a button, the user should be redirected to the login page. The user name of the respective user should be entered directly into the username field on the login page.
   How do I implement such a transition?
   The username would probably have to be passed to the server using a post call. How does the user get to the next page? Should this be a simple link or should I send the new HTML document to the user via app.sendFile()?
2. For example, how do I change

   tags in an HTML document using Node.js. The same example as before a user is logged in and redirected to the next page. Now he should be greeted with his name. The name can be read from a database using the UUID.
   How do I get this name into a

   tag?
   Do I need a template engine or are there other ways to change a static HTML page.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, security-critical parts logic be placed on the server (logging in, checking balance, authorization, etc.).

Traditionally, no code on the client side is required. You click a link/submit a form, which sends a request to a server, the server responds, the client displays the new page.

Using client side code, however, can make your app smoother and reduce the load of the server. For example: the user clicks on the shopping cart button. Instead of reloading the whole page, the user sends an ajax request, and the server responds with the cart data. Then the client updates the document, displaying the formatted cart data.

You can't "change html tags" from nodejs. You can send a response. If you send a html response, you decide how to produce the response. You can just concatenate html strings, but using a template engine is a better solution.

Comment: Then I can simply do without client-side JavaScript code at the start and only work on the server side (this can be changed later). Just to get a bit further along the learning curve. 
On the second point, briefly. If you want to change certain data on the frontend within a session. Which procedure would you prefer? That the client updates certain data using an ajax request or that you reload the whole page (using a template engine to create the new html side) or is it a mix of both?

Comment: And i just forgot. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It depends, and you can use both: For example: you navigate to /messages, which loads a completely new page. On this page, you load, refresh and send messages using ajax, without reloading the page. Search for "Single page application" and "website" terms!

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. I think I have understood the procedure now.